# InputMismatchException

Tags: java, exception

I would like to ask why I am getting an `InputMismathException`?

I have declared a variable of type `double` and when I assign it a point value e.g.(4.6) it throws me:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2456)
    at Exercises.ComputingMeanAndStandartDeviation_5_21.main(ComputingMeanAndStandartDeviation_5_21.java:18)
```

Here is the code:

```
package Exercises;

import java.util.*;

public class ComputingMeanAndStandartDeviation_5_21 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        double sum = 0;
        double number = 1;
        double counter = 1;
        System.out.println("Enter ten numbers: ");
        while(counter<10)
        {
            number = input.nextDouble();
            sum +=number;
            counter ++;
        }

        System.out.println(sum + "   " + number + " " + counter);
        double mean = sum / counter;
        System.out.println("The mean is: " + mean);
    }

}
```

Comment: Your `Scanner` object is expecting to read a `double`, but is actually seeing something that you cannot convert into a `double`

Comment: It is giving me 1
2
3
4.6
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2456)
 at Exercises.ComputingMeanAndStandartDeviation_5_21.main(ComputingMeanAndStandartDeviation_5_21.java:18)

Comment: for any floating point value it is throwing inputmismatchexcepiton

Comment: @Doesn'tMatter You should only read a double if what is actually sitting there is a `double`, try using an if statement and the `hasNextDouble()` and `hasNextInt()` methods of the Scanner class

Comment: Is it possible the machine is expecting a comma as the decimal separator (i.e.do you work for a French company for example). You can test by instantiating a java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols and calling getDecimalSeparator() and outputting what it returns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem in locale

```
Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

US decimal delimiter "."(78.12) and not ","(78,12)

Comment: Yeah buddy, you are right. I was playing before with the Locale and it is working now cheers mate

Comment: Nice answer, but do you mean US decimal (not delimiter)?