# Calculator program in Java is not working with decimals

Tags: java

I tried to compile my first calculator and the result is fine, unless I put decimal numbers like 14.6 it gives me an error. This error only occurs when I use the "." (dot symbol) and not when I use the ",". Why is that?

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class calc {
    public static void main (String args[]){
        Scanner fab = new Scanner (System.in);
        double fnum, snum, sum;
        System.out.println("Enter first number: ");
        fnum = fab.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter second number: ");
        snum = fab.nextDouble();
        sum = fnum + snum;
        System.out.println (sum);         
   }
}
```

And this is the error, in case you need it:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
    at calculator.calc.main(calc.java:9)
```

Comment: Why don't you post the relevant code and error here? If you did, you'd get a much different welcome from other members.

Comment: I did , the last link

Comment: No, you posted the code in a link. We don't want to follow links. SO has very good code formatting capabilities. Post your code and error here, _physically_.

Comment: Search for the [the error on SO like this](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=inputmismatchexception+scanner) and you'll find many likely-duplicates, eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583769/inputmismatchexception

Comment: it didn't let me paste the code in here , sorry

Comment: Describe _didn't let me_. You can go through the Help Center. It explains how to post code.

Comment: My edit adding the code was rejected.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
System.out.println(dfs.getDecimalSeparator());
```

You'll see it print out

```
,
```

The above is what the `Scanner` class does to choose its decimal separator. It appears your `Locale` uses `,` as its decimal separator.

Before creating the `Scanner` object, you can use

```
Locale.setDefault(Locale.Category.FORMAT, newLocale);
```

to set a different default `Locale` with `.` as a decimal separator.

Alternatively, you can use `Scanner#useLocale(newLocale)` to set a different `Locale` for your `Scanner` object.

Comment: so I can't use them both ?

Comment: @user3874891 No, not with `Scanner`.

Comment: ok that's all I wanted to know. thank you ! sorry if I asked the question in a wrong way . I still have to get used to this forum !

Comment: Personally, I think your question is fine now: it has a short piece of code that is complete, and you included the error and what you did to get it. For some people, your example didn't cause any problems because their default country settings use '.' for the decimal separator. But if you had known that this was the problem, you wouldn't have needed to post this question.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Ah, right. Learning experience for the OP then. It looks good to me *now* :-)

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Absolutely.

Answer (score 0):

You can read user's input as `String`'s and than use simple `if` statement, in order to check. whether given value contains un-wanted characters. If it does, than replace it, by using `String.replace(oldChar, newChar)` method.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String argsp[]) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] lines = new String[2];

        System.out.println("Enter first number:");
        lines[0] = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter second number:");
        lines[1] = scanner.nextLine();

        scanner.close();

        double[] numbers = new double[2]; 
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            if (lines[i].contains(",")) {
                lines[i] = lines[i].replace(",", ".");
                numbers[i] = Double.parseDouble(lines[i]);
            } else {
                numbers[i] = Double.parseDouble(lines[i]);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(numbers[0] + numbers[1]);
    }
}
```