# Java simple calc error

Tags: java, arrays

I just want to count these two double variables, but it stick after inputing first one variable value.
Sorry for this simple question, but I`m total beginner, thanks for you knwoledge and time guys!!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class apples {
 public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner vaclovass =  new Scanner(System.in);
        double fnum, snum, answer;
        System.out.println("Enter first num: ");
        fnum = vaclovass.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter second num: ");
        snum = vaclovass.nextDouble();
        answer = fnum + snum;
        System.out.println(answer);
    }
}
```

problem

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
    at apples.main(apples.java:8)
```

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your code.  What numbers are you typing in when you run it?

Comment: @DavidWallace Thanks man for saying that I`ve nothing done wrong with the code, it was my fault, because of new loptop and typing the value with period not comma (34.5 not 34,5 as needed). Thanks again, brotha!

Comment: @DavidWallace how could I give you more reputation brother?

Comment: possible duplicate of [InputMismatchException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583769/inputmismatchexception)

Comment: Reputation isn't a payment system.  It's for indicating the quality of questions and answers.  Since I didn't post a question or an answer here, it would be meaningless to give me reputation.

Comment: and, why is the tag array even here :P

Comment: Thanks for your knowledge, brotha!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `java.util.InputMismatchException` gets thrown (at line 8) because the input you put into the console does not match the type. For example:

```
fnum = vaclovass.nextDouble(); //assumes you input a double value, eg. 3.1, 3d, 39, 3294.39234 etc...
```

The error would occur if you print 3,4 or hello

**NOTE**: that your problem most likely occurs in that, you may have used the comma instead of a decimal sign (, or .)

This should work if you input two double values. here is a sample input (console):

```
Enter first num: 
391.2                  //first input
Enter second num:
3.2d                   //second input
394.4                  //this is your output (added answer)
```

Comment: thanks for your knowledge brotha!!

Comment: @VaclovasRekašiusJr. If the answer works, please accept it :) no problem man.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not entering a "double" like 2.5 or 3.56677. Have a look at this : stackoverflow.com/questions/14027537/

Comment: thanks for you knwoledge, brotha!!

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem is with the numbers from your input. Since they are double variables they must have floating point. In other words if you want to enter the number 3, you must enter 3.0 . I guess you are entering numbers not text.

Comment: No, entering 3 also works with doubles.

Comment: @HristoYordanov, thanks for your knowledge brotha!!