# InputMismatchException reading a decimal number

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I get the following error when entering `55.5` as answer to the first prompt. I don't get the error when entering `50`.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2413)
    at Miles.main(Miles.java:9)
Java Result: 1
```

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Miles {
    public static void main(String[] args){ 
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println ("Enter the amount of water in kilograms");
        double m = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.println ("Enter the initial temprature");
        double initialTempreture = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.println ("Enter the final termprature");
        double finalTemprature = input.nextDouble();

        double q = m * (initialTempreture - finalTemprature) * 4184;

        System.out.print (q);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try `55,5`? The decimal sign differs depending on locale.

Comment: Ideally the user should show what input was given.

Comment: possible duplicate of [InputMismatchException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583769/inputmismatchexception)

Answer (score 2):

You are living in a country where the decimal separator is not `.`.

You should change the locale with [`Scanner.useLocale(locale)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useLocale-java.util.Locale-):

```
input.useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

This way, Java will recognize `.` as the decimal separator.

If you want to know the decimal separator you are using in your default locale, you can use:

```
System.out.println(DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance().getDecimalSeparator());
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh thanks! I just found out that it does indeed work with a , as seperator. 
Ill keep this in mind :)